# React - Updating previous array with new values using useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I created a home page that contains three components `HomeHeader`, `CompanyList` and `ScrollToTopBtn`.
Focusing on `CompanyList` it is a container component that shows list of `CompanyCards` that were fetched using an API in `Home` page. List of companies are initialized in `Home` page like this

```
const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);
```

The problem is that initially after making the API call, I use spread operator to update the `companies` list like this

```
const fetchedCompanies = await fetchFeedData(page);
console.log(fetchedCompanies);
setCompanies((prevCompanies=>{return [...prevCompanies,fetchedCompanies]}));
console.log(companies);
```

But an error occurs `Uncaught TypeError: prevCompanies is not iterable`  since I believe that `companies` list is initially empty.

I tried to use another approach by using `concat` method but `companies` list stayed empty and showed `no companies found` message.

Below is the source code for `Home` page

```
const Home = () => {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1); //In order to avoid showing "no companies found" initially
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
    const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            setIsError(false);
            try {
                const fetchedCompanies = await fetchFeedData(page);
                setCompanies((prevCompanies=>{prevCompanies.concat(fetchedCompanies)})); //problem here
                setHasMore(fetchedCompanies.length > 0)
            } catch (e) {
                setIsError(true)
                setHasMore(false);
            }
            setIsLoading(false)
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [page])
    return (
        <div>
            <ScrollToTopBtn />
            <Helmet>
                <title>{stackinfo.title} - {home.title}</title>
            </Helmet>
            <HomeHeader />
            {
                isLoading ? (<LoadingSpinner />) :
                    isError ? (<ErrorBoundary message={somethingWrongError.message}></ErrorBoundary>) :
                        <CompanyList companies={companies} ></CompanyList>
            }
            <Container className={"mt-5"}>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        {(!isLoading && !isError && hasMore) && 
                        <CustomBtn
                            ButtonText={showMoreBtnText.message}
                            onClick={() => { console.log("Need to increment number of pages") }}
                        ></CustomBtn>}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I tried to check the `fetchedCompanies` and `companies` after making the API call

```
const fetchedCompanies = await fetchFeedData(page);
//Returning new array containing previous companies and recent fetchedCompanies
console.log(fetchedCompanies);
setCompanies((prevCompanies=>{prevCompanies.concat(fetchedCompanies)}));
console.log(companies);
```

`fetchedCompanies` logged an array that has 9 elements, while `companies` as mentioned above logged empty array `[]`.

Sorry if I missed something, I am still new to React.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this below to update

```js
setCompanies([...companies, ...fetchedCompanies])
```

If fetched Company are totally new Array containing all with previous record then just do it below;

```js
setCompanies([...fetchedCompanies]);
//OR
setCompanies(fetchedCompanies);
```

If you have empty strings then do this below

```js
setCompanies([...companies, ...fetchedCompanies.filter(com => !com)]);
```

Comment: I will try the first approach since the new array does not contain the previous records. There wasn't supposed to be any empty strings actually, I tried logging spread operator approach
`const fetchedCompanies = await fetchFeedData(page); console.log(fetchedCompanies); setCompanies((prevCompanies=>{return [...prevCompanies, fetchedCompanies]})); console.log(companies);` but it logged that `Uncaught TypeError: prevCompanies is not iterable` Is that because `companies` initially is an empty list?

Comment: yes, Companies initially is empty list so use my last code to achieve it

Comment: It worked as needed, I guess the problem was with spreading the `fetchedCompanies` array. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is trying to mutate state, not return a new state (or maybe you just forgot the `return` keyword?):

```
setCompanies((prevCompanies=>{prevCompanies.concat(fetchedCompanies)}));
```

Your previous attempt was closer:

```
setCompanies(prevCompanies=>{return [...prevCompanies, fetchedCompanies]});
```

But if `fetchedCompanies` is also an array as the name implies then you forgot its spread operator:

```
setCompanies(prevCompanies=>{return [...prevCompanies, ...fetchedCompanies]});
```

Without that the resulting array would be weird at best.

You can also simplify a little:

```
setCompanies(prevCompanies=>[...prevCompanies, ...fetchedCompanies]);
```

And if you don't expect these calls to overlap at all, you could potentially simplify a lot:

```
setCompanies([...companies, ...fetchedCompanies]);
```

If after that there is still an empty string then it seems that the data *has* an empty string.  In that case you'd have to filter that out manually, and where you do that is really up to you if the act of filtering might mess with the rest of the logic you have there (the `hasMore` value, for example).  But you can append `.filter()` to the resulting array any time you like.  When fetching, when updating state, or even just when rendering.

Comment: I updated my question and apologise for misexplaining the problem as there are no empty string in the array, but when I tried logging spread operator approach `const fetchedCompanies = await fetchFeedData(page); console.log(fetchedCompanies); setCompanies((prevCompanies=>{return [...prevCompanies, fetchedCompanies]})); console.log(companies);` but it logged that `Uncaught TypeError: prevCompanies is not iterable` which I believe because `companies` initially is empty, right?

Comment: It worked actually now after spreading the `fetchedCompanies` array, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You would be better to look where the empty string is coming from and try to resolve that issue but if you simple want to remove the empty string, use the following.

```
prevCompanies.concat(fetchedCompanies).filter(Boolean)
```

Comment: I edited the question and apologise for misexplaining the problem. There are no empty strings, I tried logging spread operator approach `const fetchedCompanies = await fetchFeedData(page); console.log(fetchedCompanies); setCompanies((prevCompanies=>{return [...prevCompanies, fetchedCompanies]})); console.log(companies);` but it logged that `Uncaught TypeError: prevCompanies is not iterable` I assume that it was because `companies` list initially was empty, right?